# How to write android select query to filter between the search term?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a table in my sqlite db with a list of food ingredients. If a user types "red flakes" in the search bar,

How do I write a select query which will return all the ingredients that has the term "red flakes".

E.g: user types "red flakes". This should give me results with "red chilli flakes", "red pepper flakes" as well.

This is what I have written now.

```
c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_COOKIT_INGREDIENT, null, "name LIKE ? ",
     new String[]{"%" + searchText + "%", }, null, null,
     Constants.KEY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC");
```

This only returns me "red flakes". Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the search order matter? For example, if the user types "flakes red" should they get the same results?

Answer (score 2):

For your immediate problem you could use something like:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%red%flakes%'
```

But I think you should consider investing some time to learn about SQLite's full text search capabilities.  The analogous full text search can run much faster than a `LIKE` expression.  And when your search logic becomes more complex, FTS may be your only option.

To get started you can create a virtual table and populate it with your current table data:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE table_name 
USING FTS5(name, ...);
```

Then query the table as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE name MATCH 'red AND flakes';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get results like red * flakes right?
write query as

```
WHERE name LIKE 'red%' AND name LIKE '%flakes'
```

Comment: I would use `LIKE '%red%flakes%'` which requires a single evaluation.

Comment: yeah its good, but i went above because its easier to understand. @TimBiegeleisen yours have better optimization

Comment: people really? vote down? whats wrong with this answer? could you please let me know before just putting downvotes please so then i can improve where i was wrong?

Comment: It's not my downvote, but your syntax is off.  If you wanted to go this direction you would need to use `name LIKE 'red%' AND name LIKE '%flakes'`

Comment: im just tried to help him find the right direction. and above code works too. But thanks for the letting me know why you did it so i can avoid it next time

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to get results starting with red

```
WHERE name LIKE 'red%flakes%'
```

OR

If you want results containing red---flakes any where within the text

```
WHERE name LIKE '%red%flakes%'
```